# How to read comma separated data into data frame without column header?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am getting a comma separated data set as bytes which I need to:

1. Convert in to *string* from byte
2. Create csv (can skip this if there is any way to jump to 3rd output)
3. format and read as data frame without converting first row as column name.

(Later I will be using this df to compare with oracle db output.)

Input data:

```
val = '-8335,Q1,2017,2002-07-10 00:00:00.0,-,Mr. A,4342000,AnalystA,0,F\n-8336,Q1,2017,2002-07-11 00:00:00.0,-,Mr. B,4342001,Analyst A,0,F\n-8337,Q1,2017,2002-07-10 00:00:00.0,-,Mr. C,4342002,Analyst A,0,F\n'
```

type(val)

i managed to do till step 3 but my first row is becoming header.  I am fine if we can give any value as column header e.g. a, b, c, ...

```
#1 Code I tried to convert byte to str
    strval = val.decode('ascii').strip()

#2 code to craete csv. Frist i created blank csv and later appended the data
    import csv
    import pandas as pd


    abc = ""
    with open('csvfile.csv', 'w') as csvOutput:
        testData = csv.writer(csvOutput)
        testData.writerow(abc)

    with open('csvfile.csv', 'a') as csvAppend:
        csvAppend.write(val)

#3 now converting it into dataframe

    df = pd.read_csv('csvfile.csv')


# hdf = pd.read_csv('csvfile.csv', column=none)  -- this give NameError: name 'none' is not defined
```

output:

df

[image]

Comment: [pandas.DataFrame.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)  `skiprows=1` & `header=None`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without saving to csv file like this, you don't need to convert the bytes to string or save that to file

Here `val` is of type `bytes` if it is of type string as in your example you can use `io.StringIO` instead of `io.BytesIO`

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

val = b'-8335,Q1,2017,2002-07-10 00:00:00.0,-,Mr. A,4342000,AnalystA,0,F\n-8336,Q1,2017,2002-07-11 00:00:00.0,-,Mr. B,4342001,Analyst A,0,F\n-8337,Q1,2017,2002-07-10 00:00:00.0,-,Mr. C,4342002,Analyst A,0,F\n'
buf_bytes = io.BytesIO(val)
pd.read_csv(buf_bytes, header=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) documentation it should be enough to add `header=None` as a parameter:

```
df = pd.read_csv('csvfile.csv', header=None)
```

In this way the header will be interpreted as a row of data. If you want to exclude this line then you need to add the `skiprows=1` parameter:

```
df = pd.read_csv('csvfile.csv', header=None, skiprows=1)
```